# Regex: ignore the first and last occurrence of " but not the rest

Tags: javascript, regex

I have three strings:

> 1. {{"ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'blah'"}}
> 2. {{"ErrorMsg: FATAL:  role \"foobar\" does not exist\n"}}
> 3. "{{\"param1\"}, {\"param2\"}}"

For the first 2 cases I want to get a 1-element array, while for the 3rd case I want to get a 2-element array (`['param1', 'param2']`). Following expression works for the first string:

```
/[^{"}]+(?=\"})/g
```

but doesn't work for the second string because there are two more `"` inside. How should I make it work?

You can try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/nTUoUc/4)

Comment: Can't you just `{{"(.*)"}}` ?

Comment: or event no regex but `string.slice(3,-3)`

Comment: @AlexK. `{{"(.*)"}}` is returning the full string and does not exclude `{{"` and `"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/{\\?"([^}]+?)(?=\\?"})/g
```

Matches will be available in captured group #1 that you can extract using a `while` loop calling `regex.exec(str)` in the loop.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nTUoUc/5)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
{          # match {
\\?        # match \ optionally 
"          # match a double quote
([^}]+?)   # match any character that is not a } (lazy match)
(?=\\?"})  # lookahead to assert we have optional \ followed by "}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 1):

> {{"(.*)"}} is returning the full string and does not exclude {{" and "}}

You need to extract the matched groups, simplest way:

```
str.replace(/{{"(.*)"}}/g, function(m, g) { 
    console.log(g);
});
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry, just found out I had missed a very important requirement in my question. Just updated my question. The issue is it should also cover something like `"{{\"param1\"}, {\"param2\"}}"` :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(\\\"|[^\"])+(?=\"})`

key is that it allows to include `\\\"` (escaped double quotes) OR `[^\"]` (any non-doublequotes symbols) and ended with `"}`

[regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/PjBtP2/1)